# What Is The Difference Between Google+ APIs and Google+ Domain APIs?

Tags: android, api, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I am a little confused by these APIs. I am trying to integrate Google+ with my Android app and I am struggling a little. I have been successful at logging in a **user** using OAuth2, created a Verifier, obtained an **accessToken** and made a request to Google+ API.

Here is my line of code requesting to see the user information:

```
OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me");
```

This successfully returns a jSON object containing my information/public.

Whenever I change the endpoint to this:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/circles/p4643b3a289c42c44"
```

attempting to use the **PlusDomains**, I get a forbidden message.

What I really want to do is manage circles for a user (simply add a page to their "Following" circle. That is all I need.

What am I doing wrong? Am I trying to use the wrong endpoint? Does Google+ API allow me to do POST requests?

Every piece of information is helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi i am trying to access Google Domain Api to get Person info and Circles of User, can you give me a sample code to see how it is done i am getting 403 Forbidden error. It will be very kind of you if you will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google+API and Google+Domains API are different APIs (activating/allowing one does not activate/allow the other).

The Domains API can be considered as a more powerfull (more functionnalities) than Google+API.

See comparison of the two API here on the official doc.
[Link here](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/getting-started#features_comparison)

Comment: I wouldn't say more powerful, as it is also more limited - the domains API only works on Google Apps for Domains setups, and can't work outside that (e.g. it can't create a post for a domain that is scoped any more widely than that domain). 

The Domains API is designed for management and onboarding of users on Google+ on a Apps domain. The Google+ API is designed for retrieving public information from Google+, and allowing access to app activities and people in circles for authorised users.

Comment: @lanBarber what i should use in following case..? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873495/google-api-to-send-request-from-android-app-to-google-plus