# Google API to send request from android app to google plus

Tags: android, google-api

I am developing one android application.

As we all know Facebook SDK provides functionality to send request to other users using Request Dialog.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/send-requests

I referred above link that says how we can send request to other facebook users and in response that request will be shown to the user in their profile as notification.

So my question is, Is there any same kind of API for Google Plus that i can use to send some kind of request from Android Application to Google Plus and same way as facebook my request will be shown to that users Google Plus profile?

I already used Google Plus API and OAuth2.0.

I am new to API Usage if possible then please give me the example too.

**Edit:-**

**I have found the following link which says that it is not working in Google please check out the following link.**

https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=41

**Edit :-**

Create notification in Google Plus without creating any posts in any profile.

Here the photo is just and example of game.

[image]

But in google plus.

Answer (score 4):

There is  no way to post notification like facebook using google API. 
You can create a app activity using Google+ API that will post on the user's profile without explicit user action.By default its private & hidden. User must have to take share actions to make that visible. App activities are only visible to user because its not posted directly on stream like facebook or twitter. Hence you can not achieve the same result like facebook or twitter.

For posting the application activity you can use [Google+ Moments: insert](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert). It needs to get the permission using scope from user. For android sdk use can use [Manage app activities in Google](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/app-activities)

**Scopes:**
`https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login`

Using Google App Domain can automatically create a post with visibility limited to the user or circle.
For posting the application activity you have to use [Activities: insert](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/activities/insert)

**Scopes:**
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me`

**Conclusion:** You have to take a decision to use one of the API based on your requirement. I would suggest play with both the API to check the difference & its limitation in user profile. First try with ***Google+ Domain API*** as it will post message on user stream.

Comment: As you said "App activities are only visible to user because its not posted directly on stream like facebook or twitter. Hence you can not achieve the same result like facebook or twitter." I want to create notification without posting in users profile like in facebook. Its not posting in any user's profile but it simply creates notification to invite user to play application or to give some life or anything else. Without posting to the user's profile.

Comment: I mean to say as i said without posting i want to create notification to invite.Can you put some demo?I am already using google+ api to make post on user profile using the following. https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/prefill but what i specified is i don't want to post on profile and insert moments and create notification on third person's google plus profile.

Comment: There can be any application instead of Game this is just an example. And i am not developing games so it is not related to game.

Comment: I dont think its possible. As I mentioned in first point app can post activity. But it will not share/visible to user.